# Ionic serve: how to rerun gulp task

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm kinda new to ionic and gulp.
I was able to configure the `ionic.project` file in order to run the gulp tasks when I first run `ionic serve`.
But now when I change files I want that the gulp task will run again.. But this doesn't happen.. Is there a way to do that?

This is my `ionic.project` file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "app_id": "",
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "default"
  ],
  "watchPatterns": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/*",
    "www/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I expected that when some file changes that match the `wtachPatterns`
it will invoke the gulp watch task, but this doesnt happen (I see that ionic see that the file has changed but nothing happen.)

this the the gulp watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.script, ['script']);
});
```

Basically the task is minifying all the JS files and all the sass/scss files 
and the `index.html` is looking on the minified files. so if the gulp task isn't invoked there are no changes in the minified file and I need to run `ionic serve` all over again.. Is there a proper way to do that?

UPDATE:

This is the complete gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks');


var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss'],
  style: ['./src/**/*.scss'],
  script: ['./src/app.js'],
  html:['./src/*.html']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'script','watch', 'html', 'style']);


gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.script, ['script']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download     Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-    scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

And this is an example of one of the files who have the actual task:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var stringify = require('stringify');

var paths = ['./src/app.js'];

gulp.task('script', function() {
  return browserify(paths, {debug: true})
    .transform(stringify(['.html']))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'));
});
```

Comment: show your `gulpfile.js`

Comment: what about the required file `require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks');`?

Comment: @PeteHouston I have added one of the files.

Comment: @PeteHouston Think you know?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo Yes.. look at the answer.. I had a problem with the watch paths.

Answer (score 2):

Well So the problem was with `paths` I watched.
I removed the `./` and now its working

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you misunderstand the `watchPatterns` is for livereload, which means, the web will refresh if there is any file changed on watch. It's definitely not having any relation to `gulp`.

Read more at: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html

To watch for file changes with watch, update your `watch task`, which is

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);  <-- any file in paths.sass changed will trigger `gulp sass`
  gulp.watch(paths.script, ['script']);  <-- any file in paths.script changed will trigger `gulp script`
});
```

So if you want to watch more files to be processed by Gulp, just add tasks and watch them in `gulp watch`.

Oh hey, you are watching only files in `./scss/**/*.scss` and  `./src/app.js`. Add more if you wish.

Comment: I dont understand.. bottom line.. can I run a gulp task when running ionic serve? Or in other words can the livereload run also gulp task?